# Gazebo5 ROS packages?

Tags: gazebo-5, ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Are there plans to release gazebo5 packages for ROS Indigo (i.e. ros-indigo-gazebo5-*)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7999/gazebo5-ros-packages?/) by [ahb](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/619/ahb/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-02-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After speak with Steve, Nate and the rest of the team, we have released the ROS Wrappers for Gazebo5. Only for ROS Indigo. I've created a [pull request to update the tutorial](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/pull-request/178/update-ros-wrappers-document-for-gazebo5).

```
  # if you have the packages.osrfoundation.org repository:  
  sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo5-ros-pkgs
```

ROS Jade will bring support out-of-the-box for gazebo5 and gazebo_ros_pkgs.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2015-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3